# jQuery drop down navigation with click event

Tags: jquery, menu, click

I need to create a simple (2 levels) drop down menu with jQuery. There are a lot of solutions for drop down menus in the web but they all works with hover event. To be sure that it will work in iPhone I want to use a click instead hover and I have a problems.

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="nav nav-top" id="nav">
<li><a href="#">Menu Item 1</a></li>
<li>
    <a href="#">Menu Item 2</a>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>   
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#">Menu Item 3</a>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#">Menu Item 4</a>
</li>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".nav-top > li:has(ul)").toggle(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).find('ul').show();
    $(this).addClass("expanded"); //This class set display:block to UL
},
function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).find('ul').hide();
    $(this).removeClass("expanded");
});

$(".nav-top > li:has(ul) ul").mouseup(function() {
    return false
});
$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
    if($(e.target).parent(".nav-top > li a").length==0) {
        $(".nav-top > li:has(ul)").removeClass("expanded");
        $(".nav-top > li:has(ul) ul").hide();
    }
});
```

});

It do not work correct. If click "Menu Item 2" then some where instead of menu and then again "Menu Item 2" it will not show drop down (see example: http://test.xhtml4u.ru/go/test.html ), I think the reason in .toggle function, but do not know how to fix it.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You do a $(".nav-top > li:has(ul)") but what I see is <ul class="nav">. Should this be the case?

Comment: Thank for note, just bad copy/paste, should be <ul class="nav nav-top" id="nav">.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [DEMO jsBin](http://jsbin.com/otuyar/edit#javascript,html,live)

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".nav-top > li").click(function(e) {
    if($(this).has('ul')){
      $('.expanded').removeClass('expanded').hide();
    }
    $(this).find('ul').addClass('expanded').show();
  });

  $('.nav-top a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks man. I've also added function to remove drop down with document click and it works perfect.